# How to make custom dialogs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I have 9 `imageButton` in my activity view and they're defined by id's such as `imageButton1 ~ imageButton9` I need to create `dialog/alert/popup` either of them in order to show more details regarding to each image button.

## Question

As this is my very first attempt with android studio and I've read docs also some websites posts about dialogs yet it is very confusing to me, **so the question is how do i create dialogs for each of imageButtons?**

## Code

`xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        tools:context=".ShapesActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#006B2D2D"
                android:contentDescription="@string/triangleDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/triangle" />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#006B2D2D"
                android:contentDescription="@string/trapezoidDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/trapezoid" />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#006B2D2D"
                android:contentDescription="@string/starDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/star" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#006B2D2D"
                android:contentDescription="@string/squareDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/square" />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#006B2D2D"
                android:contentDescription="@string/rectangleDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/rectangle" />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#006B2D2D"
                android:contentDescription="@string/octagonDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/octagon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="357dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#006B2D2D"
                android:contentDescription="@string/heartDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/heart" />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#007E2F2F"
                android:contentDescription="@string/diamondDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/diamond" />

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00E040FB"
                android:contentDescription="@string/circleDesc"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`kotlin file`

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

class ShapesActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shapes)

        val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar;
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //menu items actions
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater as MenuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.settings_page -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                val intent = Intent(this, SettingActivity::class.java);
                startActivity(intent);
            };
            true
        }

        else -> {
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

## Logic

I need to have 4 item in each dialog (different data for each imageButton),

1. Image
2. Text
3. Play sound Button
4. Dialog Close Button

Any idea?

## Update

Based on answer below here is latest codes that I have

`dialog_custom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="246dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="274dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="270dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="474dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="154dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="274dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="680dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:background="#F50057"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="680dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="292dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:background="#00E676"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Play"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity kotlin file`

```
class BuildingsActivity : BaseActivity() {

    lateinit var mAdView : AdView;
    lateinit var context : Context

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buildings)


        // open dialog
        val imageButton1 = this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1) as ImageButton;
        imageButton1.setOnClickListener() {
            openDialog();
        }

    }

    // button dialog
    public fun openDialog() {
        val dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)

        val tv_text = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_text)as TextView
        val btn_close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_btn) as Button
        val btn_play = dialog.findViewById(R.id.play_btn) as Button
        val imageView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview) as ImageView

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.school) //set image here
        tv_text.setText("School")  // set description here


        //insert your button function here
        btn_close.setOnClickListener {
            fun onClick(v: View) {
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }

        btn_play.setOnClickListener {
            fun onClick(v: View) {
                val mp: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a)
                mp?.start();
            }
        }

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

## Problem

when I click on image that supposed to open this dialog my screen becomes blank and return to main activity.

**Ideas?**

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076779/kotlin-custom-dialog-in-android

Comment: @L2_Paver thanks for the link i've already tried that the issue is, with that code then i have to make 9 `cutsom_layout` files what i'm looking for is to skip making xml file/having empty template and have my static data for each imageButton in my activity. this way i will have 9 different function instead of 9 different xml files

Comment: you can do it dynamically without creating 9 layouts, just supply the image and text from your activity to the custom dialog.

Comment: @L2_Paver would you mind give me sample code in answer as i said I'm complete newbie in android studio :)

Comment: I am not familiar at kotlin yet, I can give you a sample java code.

Comment: that's fine android studio helps to convert it in kotlin

Comment: try this https://medium.com/@xabaras/creating-a-custom-dialog-with-dialogfragment-f0198dab656d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: did it crashed?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes it did

Comment: post the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Try this, your btnclose and btnplay have unnecessary codes

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var imageButton1 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton1) as ImageButton //add your imagebuttons here

        imageButton1.setOnClickListener { // provide/add setsetOnClickListener for all imagebutton 

            val description = imageButton1.getContentDescription().toString()
            val drawable = imageButton1.getDrawable()
            val mp = MediaPlayer.create(R.raw.imageButton1soundDialogCustom())

            openDialog(drawable, description, mp)
        }

    }

     fun openDialog(drawable: Drawable, description: String, mp: MediaPlayer ) {
        val dialog = Dialog(this@MainActivity)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)

        val tvtext  = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_text)as TextView
        val btnclose = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_btn) as Button
        val btnplay = dialog.findViewById(R.id.play_btn) as Button
        val imageView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview) as ImageView

        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)//set image here
        tvtext.setText(description)

        btnclose.setOnClickListener {

                dialog.dismiss()

        }

        btnplay.setOnClickListener {

            val mp: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a)
            mp?.start()
        }

         dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do i add buttons in dialog? each dialog has 2 buttons (close and play sound) obviously sound of each dialog is different.

Comment: how do you declare/play your sound? via mediaplayer?

Comment: Hi, I've made new class and dialog xml based on your answer but i have errors as well as couldn't figure how to connect it in my image buttons! (sorry i don't mean to act stupid but it's my very first time with android studio bear with me please) `screenshot` http://ibb.co/WNXhYQb `class code` http://codepile.net/pile/257OzY5E `xml code` http://codepile.net/pile/OLjGxPAQ

Comment: does this anyhow helps? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs i can't understand it! :| to complected

Comment: this how you declare your widget on kotllin `var btn_new_activity = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_new_activity) as Button`

Comment: and this how you declare your onClickListener `btn_new_activity.setOnClickListener {}` can't open your codes btw and the topic you post is about Alert Dialogs. Alert dialogs are not recommended in creating complex layout.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question would you take a look at it please?

Comment: You could extend FragmentDialog rather than just make a basic class with a method that might as well be static

Comment: hi, what is this? `imageButton1soundDialogCustom` it's red colored in my editor

Comment: Your sound file name on raw folder

Comment: then why it has `()` seems like it's a function?!

Comment: anyway i've got it to work thanks to you, there is small problem please see this screenshot https://ibb.co/KNwHr7H the width of dialog isn't right.

Comment: '()' was a typo, Try posting/update your custom_dialog.xml above, I will review it on monday.