# How to set the cancel button to right end corner in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created an alert dialog box, but I have facing a problem of my cancel button in left end side, I required it should be in right end side.

```
invest_more_bank_info_iv.setOnClickListener {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialogMessage)
    builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel") { dialogInterface, which ->
        Toast.makeText(context, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
    alertDialog.show()

    val positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
    positiveButton.gravity = Gravity.END
}
```

Comment: you should follow the guidelines of google https://material.io/components/dialogs/, read for more info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin - custom dialog in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076779/kotlin-custom-dialog-in-android)